# Python tkinter - numpy - Listbox doesn't load values

Tags: python, numpy, tkinter, listbox, ttk

I'm building a python tkinter software with a listbox, but the listbox doesn't load values from a list (that is inside a dictionary) through for loop.

The dictionary is stored in a .npy file with numpy and has this structure: `m={"subject":["subjectname"], ...}`. But I don't think the problem is caused by the file or the dictionary because it works well with a ttk combobox...

Here is my code:

```
import os.path
import numpy as np
global m
global fn_sub
global path
m={}
# filename for the file to save
fn_sub = "subjects.npy"

path = os.path.expanduser(r'~\Documents\School Life Diary')
# check the directory does not exist
if not(os.path.exists(os.path.join(path,fn_sub))):
    # write the file in the new directory
    np.save(os.path.join(path, fn_sub), m)
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.messagebox
from tkinter.ttk import *
global old_mat
def inizializza():
        try:
            m=np.load(os.path.join(path, fn_sub)).item()
        except ValueError:
            m={}
### other code... ###
def creaFinestra():
    global wim
    wim=Toplevel()
    inizializza()
    wim.title("Materie - School Life Diary")
    wim.iconbitmap("sld_icon_beta.ico")
    wim.geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d" % (325, 325, 600, 200))
    s=Style()
    try:
        s.theme_use("vista")
    except:
        s.theme_use()
    fim=Frame(wim)
    fim.pack()
    global lb
    lb=Listbox(fim,selectmode="SINGLE")
    lb.pack(padx=10,pady=10)
    for e in m:
        lb.insert("end",*m[e])
    ''' I also used this, but doesn't work...
    for e in m:
        lb.insert(list(m.keys()).index(e),m[e][0])
    '''
    fim2=Frame(wim)
    fim2.pack()
    imageAdd=PhotoImage(file=r"images/add_FAB.png")
    imageMod=PhotoImage(file=r"images/mod_FAB.png")
    imageDel=PhotoImage(file=r"images/trash_FAB.png")
    bAdd=Button(fim2,image=imageAdd,command=add)
    bAdd.image=imageAdd
    bMod=Button(fim2,image=imageMod,command=edit)
    bDel=Button(fim2,image=imageDel,command=delete)
    bAdd.grid(row=0,column=0,padx=10,pady=10)
    bMod.grid(row=0,column=1,padx=10,pady=10)
    bDel.grid(row=0,column=2,padx=10,pady=10)
    wim.mainloop()
```

Can you help me?
Thanks

Comment: What does "doesn't load values" mean? Do you get an error? Does it load the wrong data? Does it load the right data in the wrong format? Have you verified that `m[e]` contains what you think it contains?

Comment: 1. I mean the listbox is empty and the data isn't added into the listbox

2. No
3. No
4. No
5. I tried with `print(m[e])` but it doesn't print... it seems that the for loop doesn't be runned...

Comment: The first thing you need to do is verify that your variable has data in it. If it doesn't, the problem isn't with the listbox.

Comment: Bryan see my comment above

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem:
Numpy loads the dictionary but the variable m will be lost forever if I don't add `global m`before.
So I rechecked the code and added some more controls. Here it is the fully functional code:

```
import os.path
import numpy as np
global m
m={}
global fn_sub
global path
# filename for the file you want to save
fn_sub = "subjects.npy"

path = os.path.expanduser(r'~\Documents\School Life Diary')
# check the directory does not exist
if not(os.path.exists(os.path.join(path,fn_sub))):
    # write the file in the new directory
    m={}
    np.save(os.path.join(path, fn_sub), m)

from tkinter import *
import tkinter.messagebox
from tkinter.ttk import *
#Variabili globali
global old_mat

def inizializza():
    try:
        global m
        m=np.load(os.path.join(path, fn_sub)).item()
    except ValueError:
        m={}
def Salvataggio(mode,var):
    try:
        if mode=="add":
            m[var.get()]=[var.get()]
            wa.destroy()
        elif mode=="edit":
            m[old_mat][0]=var.get()
            we.destroy()
        elif mode=="del":
            del m[old_mat]
        np.save(os.path.join(path, fn_sub), m)
        tkinter.messagebox.showinfo(title="Successo!", message="Salvataggio effettuato con successo!")
        wim.destroy()
        creaFinestra()
    except:
        tkinter.messagebox.showerror(title="Errore!", message="Si è verificato un errore, riprovare oppure contattare lo sviluppatore")

def delete():
    if lb.get(lb.curselection())=="":
        tkinter.messagebox.showerror(title="Nessuna materia selezionata",
                                     message="ERRORE! Nessuna materia selezionata!")
        return ""
    global old_mat
    old_mat=lb.get(lb.curselection())
    try:
        scelta=tkinter.messagebox.askyesno(title="Conferma eliminazione",
                                message="Si è sicuri di voler eliminare la materia "+old_mat+"?")
    except TypeError:
        scelta=tkinter.messagebox.askyesno(title="Conferma eliminazione",
                                message="Si è sicuri di voler eliminare la materia "+old_mat[0]+"?")
    if scelta==True:
        Salvataggio("del","")
    else:
        return ""
def add():
    global wa
    wa=Toplevel()
    wa.title("Inserisci materia - School Life Diary")
    wa.iconbitmap("sld_icon_beta.ico")
    wa.geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d" % (200, 200, 600, 200))
    l=Label(wa, text="Inserire la nuova materia")
    l.pack(padx=10,pady=10)
    var=StringVar(value="")
    e=Entry(wa, textvariable=var)
    e.pack(padx=10,pady=10)
    b=Button(wa, text="SALVA", command=lambda: Salvataggio("add",var))
    b.pack(padx=10,pady=10)
    wa.mainloop()

def edit():
    global old_mat
    old_mat=lb.get(lb.curselection())
    global we
    we=Toplevel()
    we.title("Modifica materia - School Life Diary")
    we.iconbitmap("sld_icon_beta.ico")
    we.geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d" % (450, 200, 600, 200))
    l=Label(we, text="Inserire la materia da modificare (Vecchia materia: "+old_mat+")")
    l.pack(padx=10,pady=10)
    var=StringVar(value="")
    e=Entry(we, textvariable=var)
    e.pack(padx=10,pady=10)
    b=Button(we, text="SALVA", command=lambda: Salvataggio("edit",var))
    b.pack(padx=10,pady=10)
    we.mainloop()
def riempiListbox(lb):
    for e in m:
        lb.insert(list(m.keys()).index(e),m[e][0])
def creaFinestra():
    global wim
    wim=Toplevel()
    inizializza()
    wim.title("Materie - School Life Diary")
    wim.iconbitmap("sld_icon_beta.ico")
    wim.geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d" % (325, 325, 600, 200))
    s=Style()
    try:
        s.theme_use("vista")
    except:
        s.theme_use()
    fim=Frame(wim)
    fim.pack()
    global lb
    lb=Listbox(fim,selectmode="SINGLE")
    lb.pack(padx=10,pady=10)
    riempiListbox(lb)
    fim2=Frame(wim)
    fim2.pack()
    imageAdd=PhotoImage(file=r"images/add_FAB.png")
    imageMod=PhotoImage(file=r"images/mod_FAB.png")
    imageDel=PhotoImage(file=r"images/trash_FAB.png")
    bAdd=Button(fim2,image=imageAdd,command=add)
    bAdd.image=imageAdd
    bMod=Button(fim2,image=imageMod,command=edit)
    bDel=Button(fim2,image=imageDel,command=delete)
    bAdd.grid(row=0,column=0,padx=10,pady=10)
    bMod.grid(row=0,column=1,padx=10,pady=10)
    bDel.grid(row=0,column=2,padx=10,pady=10)
    wim.mainloop()
```

Thanks for your help!